# How to loop thru elements in Selenium with C# using xpath using partial id

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a bunch of divs. I am looping thru them using their class name: `col-lg-3`. In each of the divs by the class name above, I have xpaths like the ones below. I need to pick out the string value at `td[4]`

```
.//*[@id='item-186951']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]
.//*[@id='itemPNS18-152951']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]
.//*[@id='itemXYZ-8152951']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]
.//*[@id='item11641551']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]
.//*[@id='itemAPS12641']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]
```

This part is the one that is changing in every element `[@id='{dynamically-changing-id}']`, with the rest being constant. How do I loop over this? At the moment I am trying this but I only get the first item (understandably)

```
        //get all divs on page
        var elements = ...FindElements(By.ClassName("col-lg-3"));
        //for each div found
        foreach(var e in elements)
        {
            //get text at xpath
            string str = e.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='item-186951']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]"));
        }
```

Im using Selenium 2.53

Comment: anyway you could post some html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that `id` attribute [starts with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) "item":

```
var elements = ThisPage.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[starts-with(@id, 'item')]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]"))
```